# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for active model and active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

***controller***

```
def new
  @query.query_string = params[:query][:query_string]
end
```

***model***

```
def query_string=(query_str)
  @query_string = query_str
  @query_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_str)
end
```

***view***

```
<%= form_for @query, url: queries_new_path, method: "get" do |f| %>
<td><%= f.text_field :query_string %></td>
```

I have just shown the abstarct of my code.it returns `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

Could any one tell the solution to this problem

Comment: From the error it looks like `params[:query]` returns `Nil`, because you are looking for a nested param which does not exist for Nil. To fix this try changing your for method to `method: "post"` and create a `create` action

Comment: can anyone please tell ajax implementation on this to display the output.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER TO YOUR INITIAL QUESTION: From the error it looks like `params[:query]` returns `Nil`, because you are looking for a nested param which does not exist for `Nil`. To fix this try changing your for method to `method: "post"` and create a `create` action.

AJAX IMPLEMENTATION:

1. Add `remote: true` to your form, so it should be something like:

   ```
   <%= form_for @query, url: queries_new_path, method: "post", remote: true do |f| %>
   ```

2.in your `create` action add this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {}
end
```

3. create a `create.js.erb` file, where you can define the ajax callbacks(what gets rendered, hidden and so on). If you do `@query.save` or something similar in your create action, you can just do it in the view like so:

   ```
   <% if @query.save %>
     $(".some_success_block").html("some success message")
   <% else %>
     $(".some_outter_div_around_form").html("<%= j render 'form' %>")
   <% end %>
   ```

this requires that you have a partial view named `_form.html.erb` with your form in it.

Then you can substitute form in your `new.html.erb` with just `<%= render "form" %>`

And that should do it.

More info about AJAX in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax